# A custom validation for checkbox_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Ok, I have this in my `_form.html.erb`

```
 <div class "field">
   <%= label_tag "What days of the week do you want to work with us? (maximum of three days)" %>
    <span>What days of the week do you want to work with us? (maximum of three days)</span><br />
    <%= check_box_tag 'days_of_week[]', "Monday" %> Monday
    <%= check_box_tag 'days_of_week[]', "Tuesday" %> Tuesday
    <%= check_box_tag 'days_of_week[]', "Wednesday" %> Wednesday
    <%= check_box_tag 'days_of_week[]', "Thursday" %> Thursday
    <%= check_box_tag 'days_of_week[]', "Friday" %> Friday
    <%= check_box_tag 'days_of_week[]', "Saturday" %> Saturday
    <%= check_box_tag 'days_of_week[]', "Sunday" %> Sunday
  </div>
```

How do I write a custom validation for it to ensure that a person does check three or less?

Here's a little background that complicates it a bit .. look at the code below, see @new_partnership? it's not part of that ... it does show up in parameters, but not in :new_partnership parameters.

just wanted to explain that.

```
       <%= form_for(@new_partnership) do |f| %>
           <% if @new_partnership.errors.any? %>
           <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@new_partnership.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this new_partnership from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
            <% @new_partnership.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
             <li><%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
             </ul>
             </div>
        <% end %>
```

Please let me know if there is additional info should I have  to give.

EDIT 1

Also, before anyone suggests jQuery, etc ... is there a way to validate this just in ROR without having to resort to it?

You know, something like this: 
        `validates :days_of_week, :presence => { :message => "Must check three or less" }`

two problems from the statement above, one is that ROR says that days_of_week is undefined method (obviously since it's a custom tag) and secondly, it doesn't actually check to see if 3 or less checkboxes were checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can always construct free-form validators with `validates_each`:

```
validates_each :days_of_week do |record, attr, value|
  record.errors.add attr, ' must have 3 or fewer checked.' if value.length > 3;
end
```

Note that for this to work your model must be able to use an array-valued attribute, which probably requires specialized accessors.

What you wrote in the "background" part of your question doesn't signify anything as far as I can see.

Comment: hm, in other words, (pardon my ignorance btw) i need to do migration to add the accessor for days_of_weeks since it's not part of new_partnership parameter array? is that what you meant?

Comment: also the "background" part was meant to show that days_of_week was not part of the new_partnership array since it's a custom tag of its own. just wanted to clarify that. sorry, i'm sorta new to ruby on rails and am not quite sure what's important and what's not.

Comment: Your checkboxes are represented with variable-length array in `params`.  Rails ActiveRecord doesn't deal with array-valued attributes by itself. You'd need to define your own way of encoding days of week in a database field and implement them in accessors.